# Select a specific value of Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project where I generate a dropdown where the user can choose one of several values in a form (I work with Symfony and Twig if that's important). Everything is working fine, but I do not really know how to choose a certain value to be chosen (for instance a user's favorite color can be changed, but if it is already known to be blue, I would like blue to be selected before changing anything).

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="col-cs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <input type="hidden" class="choice-to-click" value="Second">
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="category_ReceipientTemplateID" title="Kérem válasszon"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Kérem válasszon</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu open">
            <div class="bs-searchbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
                <li data-original-index="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Kérem válasszon</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
                <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">asda</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <select id="category_ReceipientTemplateID" name="category[ReceipientTemplateID]" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Kérem válasszon</option>
            <option value="40">First</option>
            <option value="42">Second</option>
            <option value="43">Third</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's suppose the second value should be chosen beforehand, so both in the case when I do not interact with this control, or click on the button to type some value, my option `Second` should be chosen. The question is how can I do this in an elegant manner?

My current solution looks like this:

```
define(['jquery1_11'], function(jq) 
{
    var $ = jq;
    return function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".choice-to-click").each(function() {
                var valueToSearch = this.value;
                $(this).siblings(".bootstrap-select").find(".dropdown-menu.inner .text").filter(function() {
                    return this.innerText === valueToSearch;
                }).click();
            });
        }, 1000);
    };
});
```

But this is a very ugly hack. It works, but I am not proud of it. Essentially I am waiting for a second for Bootstrap to do its job, initialize everything, then I automatically click on the item I need. Is there a way I can tell Bootsrap somehow to choose a given value?

Comment: I solved that same problem in a very similar way, except the timeout. You could attach to some DOM event, like `<document fully loaded>` or `<select value changed>`.

Comment: @MarioCianciolo your suggestion is better than my current solution, but it is still not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to initialize my `selectpicker`, like this:

```
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

and when it is initialized, I can easily `click` on any of its items:

```
    $(".choice-to-click").each(function() {
        var valueToSearch = this.value;
        $(this).siblings(".bootstrap-select").find(".dropdown-menu.inner .text").filter(function() {
            return this.innerText === valueToSearch;
        }).click();
    });
```

I know I am still clicking, but at least I got rid of `setTimeout`. If anyone can come up with a more elegant solution, I will gladly accept his or her answer. Otherwise I will have to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = ["2017-01-15T19:18:13.000Z", "2016-11-24T17:33:56.000Z", "2017-04- 
24T00:41:18.000Z", "2017-03-06T01:45:29.000Z", "2017-03-05T03:30:40.000Z"];
_.sortBy(users, String);
```